# How to prohibit printing invoice when the client address field is empty

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-9

I'm using odoo and i want to prohibit printing invoices when client adresse is empty any idea for help please ? How can'i verify if this field or any other field is empty or not 
this the function of printing i tried this code but nothing is happend

```
      def invoice_print(self,cr,uid,values):
    """ Print the invoice and mark it as sent, so that we can see more
        easily the next step of the workflow
    """
    res_partner = self.pool.get('res.partner')
    adresse_partner = res_partner.browse(cr, uid, values.get('partner_id')).street
    code_tva_partner = res_partner.browse(cr, uid, values.get('partner_id')).CodeTVA
    if (code_tva_partner==False)or (adresse_partner==False) :
        raise UserError(_(
            "you cannot print invoice unless you enter partner adress and code TVA "))
    elif (code_tva_partner==True) and (adresse_partner==True):
      self.ensure_one()
      self.sent = True
    return self.env['report'].get_action(self, 'account.report_invoice')
```

Comment: Is this really necessary? `partner_id` in `self` which is a recordset of `account.invoice` is already a related field and you should be able to get related partner by just using `.` operator, like `self.partner_id`. Or at least odoo 11 version works that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this function self is the record of invoice model that you are trying `partner_id` which is the client record for this invoice. All you have to do is add a `if` condition on `self.partner_id.street` and if that field is False which means not set, return a kind of warning. Which will prevent invoice from printing if the client has no address associated.

Comment: I started working with Odoo11, never had the chance to work with version 9, so field names may differ.